# È obbligatorio usare la maiuscola dopo un punto interrogativo o esclamativo?

Tags: punctuation, capitalization, orthography

È obbligatorio usare la maiuscola dopo un punto interrogativo o esclamativo?

Comment: +1 Pensavo che la risposta fosse "_ovviamente_ sempre maiuscola". Non essendo così, anche la domanda assume dunque un senso!

Answer (score 13):

Come si legge sulla [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/maiuscola_%28Enciclopedia-dell%27Italiano%29/):

> Dopo il punto interrogativo e il punto esclamativo l’uso della
>   maiuscola non dipende da una regola fissa, benché la prassi più
>   diffusa tra gli scriventi sia quella di scrivere una maiuscola (va
>   notato inoltre, che il correttore ortografico del programma Word
>   riconduce sempre a maiuscola). L’impiego varia da caso a caso a
>   seconda dell’intenzione dello scrivente di segnalare o meno una pausa
>   forte, con interruzione di periodo; e lo stesso vale dopo i puntini di
>   sospensione.

Comment: Anche il correttore ortografico di tutti gli *smartphone* che ho avuto occasione di provare seguono la stessa convenzione.

Answer (score 2):

Aggiungo un esempio dai Promessi Sposi (https://it.wikisource.org/wiki/I_promessi_sposi/Capitolo_I)

> Che fare? tornare indietro, non era a tempo: darla a gambe, era lo stesso che dire, inseguitemi, o peggio.

In genere, se c'è un gruppo di domande di fila si dovrebbe usare il minuscolo, anche se mi sa che la maggior parte degli insegnanti segnerebbe errore.

Comment: Una semplice regola del pollice potrebbe essere questa: se la domanda è un intercalare allora dopo il punto interrogativo ci va la minuscola. A volte dopo il punto interrogativo ci va addirittura la virgola!!!